# Color not being inherited by child elements?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to simplify the HTML below as much as possible.
Why does the CSS property, `color: #01FFDD;`, get ignored by all the elements of the nested table?  Nested CSS using `<div>` works in general for me, but not here. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css" > #features{color: #01FFDD;}     </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="features">
                        <h2>FEATURES</h2>
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h2>HEADING 1</h2>
                                    <p> SOME TEXT</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h2> HEADING 2</h2>
                                    <p>SOME TEXT</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/R9dcC/)!

Comment: Worked fine for me. What are you expecting?

Comment: Are these the only styles on the page?  It works for me as is.

Comment: i expect all the text to be cyan, but i'm only seeing the text, "FEATURES", in cyan, the rest is default black.

Comment: it's not just color, i tried font-size as well.

Comment: Reproduced in Safari 5.1. When I inspect, it shows a UA stylesheet for `table` with `color: -webkit-text;`. This is probably conformant insofar as the UA stylesheet is allowed to be anything, but does seem strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a quirks-mode type of issue, at least as I reproduced it in Safari 5.1 — depending on the DOCTYPE, the UA stylesheet contains the rule

```
table {
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: medium;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: -webkit-text;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
}
```

Note the `color` property.

To avoid this, change your `<!DOCTYPE>` to the official W3C recommendation for HTML 4.01 Transitional:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css"> #features, #features table{color: #01FFDD;} </style>
```

Comment: this definitely works.  do u know why it doesn't work the other way?