# table does not inherit color css property from body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I see the `color` style is inherited from `body` for a table at http://getbootstrap.com/css/. 
[image]
But, when I use it, it is not inherited and `-webkit-text` is applied. 
[image]
When is the inheritance stops? I have a `div` enclosing this table, which has the `color` inherited from `body`. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `color`-element is inherited to all children, but the `border-color` property overrides it. (Source: http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspcolor.htm)

Also, to avoid the -webkit-text-issue it appears you should change the `<!DOCTYPE>` into

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

(Source: [Color not being inherited by child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493386/color-not-being-inherited-by-child-elements))