# CSS style does not apply, style depth limit?

Tags: html, css, limit, depth

I have the following problem:

I get a generated HTML with dynamic content. The IDs and the html tag-hierarchy is always the same. I can set a stylesheet.

I tried to set the color of the text to red. If I set it on this position where it's done in the screenshot it does not work. If I set it inline in the table below (table cols=2 border=0...) it works.

[image: Code snipset]

Is there a depth limit for CSS ? How can I set the color for the whole text containing the div (id=15B_gr or id=oReportCell) ?

---

++UPDATE++

I tried to set a stylesheet, but it does not work:
[image: Code snipset 2]
[image: Css part 1]
[image: Css part 2]

Comment: ID's should not start with a number

Comment: without seeing your CSS, I would suggest this is a selector specificity issue. If you have set `id=15B_gr` as black text for example and are not able to make its distant grand-child display red text. You can read about selector specificity  here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn He's currently trying to use inline styles on an outer `<div>` but they are not inherited by the innermost `<span>`.

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ OP says it's generated html and from what the other ids look like it's a report rendering engine, so it could well be out of his control.

Comment: the id is generated by the report engine, that is right. And I do not apply a stylesheet at this time.

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ [from html 5 on the value of the `id` attribute may start with a number](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/datatypes.html#common.data.id)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Color not being inherited by child elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493386/color-not-being-inherited-by-child-elements)

Comment: I tried already to set the text-align, it is not inherited too.

Comment: @NicoO thanks for that, did not know that. I wonder if his doctype is declared as html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to target all the children of a div by using an asterisk. In this case:

```
#15B_gr * {
    color:red;
}
```

or you could set it on just the  elements:

```
#15B_gr span {
    color:red;
}
```

** Edit for further information **

As pointed out by @nico o, some complications can arise due to having a number as the first character in the ID.  Previous versions of the HTML spec did not allow IDs to begin with a number.

http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/datatypes.html#common.data.id

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. I updated my question.

Comment: I see. If that's the inspection then they are already set to !important; (which is really unfortunate). You could do the same, as the last !important; rule will take precedence, but this is an extreme circumstance.

Comment: An ID can not begin with a number (thanks to Nico O) then I applied the asterisk to the oReportCell, then it works.

Comment: As the actual solution was because id (and class names) should not start with a number. This answer is irrelevant and the answer should not be accepted without a solution written by the answerer.

Comment: @DanielCheung That only applies to previous versions of HTML but I will add it to the answer since it is still relevant in many cases.

Comment: @DanielCheung Setting the wildcard style on an element with a valid id did solve the issue so the answer is acceptable. I'd much rather blame the second answer because it totally fails to acknowledge that the OP already uses the style inspector, already uses !important and that no other stylesheets are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a rule (in another stylesheet?) which has a selector which has the elements class that you want to style but additionally the class name of an element of a parent or grandparent element. In this case that specific style would outweight your style.

In this case you could add an "!important" to your rule (color: red !important; ) ...

or you could add the selectors of the other stylesheets style to yours too so that that style doesn't outweight your's anymore.

You should "inspect" the element! (Rightclick on it, "inspect element") to find the active and overwritten rules for that specific element! You find those info in the lower right corner of the "inspector"-Window wich then opens. Along with the currently active styles you there find the stylesheet in which the styles are defined.